# Is there any way to apply a modifier to multiple objects in order to make an animation?

Tags: animation, modifiers, keyframes, dopesheet

i'm making an animation of the objects (you can see them in the image) and as you can see they are separate objects, the thing is i want to curve/animate the objects separately with the SimpleDeform modifier (i need to make them 'move' as if they were underwater, but just sightly), but they are a lot, and i want an animation kind of ''harmonius'', so i wanted to know if there's any option to apply the modifier to all objects and then just move/modify keyframes on the dopesheet.

**Is this possible? Thanks in regard.**

[image]

Comment: It didnt worked, it still just applies to one object

Comment: It might not be possible, but you might be able to link to modifiers between multiple objects. I can, t remember the shortcut, though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> gives you the option to link the modifiers from the active object to all other selected objects.

This will overwrite the modifiers of the object being copied to, so there is a really useful plugin to copy any one of the modifiers and not overwrite others, which is called: *3D View: Copy Attributes Menu*.

When this is enabled, use the hotkey <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to bring up the menu options, and use the *copy selected modifiers* option to copy your modifier.